# Component Dependency Matrix for JavaScript

Tags: library, javascript, data-visualization, dependencies, matrix

To get an overview of the complexity of my JavaScript application I want to get something like a Dependency Structure Matrix. I found a tool for Java code ([junkdog/ecs-matrix](https://github.com/junkdog/ecs-matrix)) but not for JavaScript code.

Do you know a library or tool that can show me the connections of my JavaScript functions like which function is calling which?